# Segmentation fault in C code compiled with g++ accessing global 2D char array index

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, g++

The job at hand is to use string array and access each string using index. The code is working great but sometime it ends up in segmentation fault with "error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1"

Taken out the snippet from large piece of code for better readability.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char str_map[][12] = {
   "abc",
   "def",
   "lmn"
};

char *getStrMapAtIndex(unsigned char index)
{
    if((sizeof(str_map)/sizeof(str_map[0])) <= index) return NULL;
    else return str_map[index];
}

printf("%s\n",getStrMapAtIndex(1));
```

I have multiple such maps defined at global scope. This program is working with no issues every time I execute on my local machine but some time crash on the krait CPU.

Please note: the map is defined in one file along with API to return pointer at array index, but the pointer used in another file.

I tried searching all over the place in internet but get no clue of what can potentially go wrong with global array initialization leading the API to return address "0x1".

Did anybody faced similar issue in your experience?
Any help or clue is appreciated.

Comment: This is going to be really tough to answer without a [mcve].

Comment: Your problem is strictly one of C programming and has nothing to do
with numerical programming in particular.Somewhere in your code you have an invalid pointer, most likely one that was never initialized properly to point to any data.If you need more clarification visit                                           http://computer-programming-forum.com/17-c-language/91171078d803c0ab.htm

Comment: The crash is not reproducible at will and work most of the time. Yes there are uninitialized pointers before the call, but they are defined under local scope.

Comment: Did you try running it in a debugger to get the address of your segmentation fault?

Comment: Why do you compile C code with g++? That's a very bad idea.

Comment: "Please note: the map is defined in one file along with API to return pointer at array index, but the pointer used in another file." What pointer? How exactly do you do the spaghetti declaration in the other file? It should be `extern char str_map[3][12] `. If it's something else, then that may be the cause. For example `extern char* str_map;` ... `sizeof(str_map)` obviously won't work.

Comment: What I meant is ```char str_map[][12]``` definition and API ```getStrMapAtIndex(...)``` are in the same C file. The API is accessed from another C file. All the files are part of single executable.